# Spring Web Flow + Jquery ajax + JSON

Tags: java, ajax, json, jquery, spring-webflow

I am trying to call the method inside the controller through the jquery get or post.
However in the success data i am getting complete html. I am expecting the JSON object returned should be available.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options: one of them is using Jettison for marshalling, as described in the following article: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html.

Another way is serializing your return in JSON using JSON Marshaller: https://code.google.com/p/jsonmarshaller/